# Set different font as per title and subtitle in UIlabel IBDesignable

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, ibdesignable

I had created the custom class for uilabel with below code:

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomUILabel: UILabel {

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureLabel()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        configureLabel()
    }

    func configureLabel() {
        textColor = .white
        font = UIFont(name: Constants.regularFontName, size: 14)
    }
}
```

This help me to set the font through out the application.But i wanted to create different bold font type for title and regular font for subtitle.
Is this possible only with one file ? 
Or i need to create different Extension for that type of UIlabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example add a custom `style` property like this:

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomUILabel: UILabel {

    enum CustomUILabelStyle {
        case title, subtitle

        var font: UIFont? {
            switch self {
            case .title:
                return UIFont(name: Constants.boldFontName, size: 14)
            case .subtitle:
                return UIFont(name: Constants.regularFontName, size: 14)
            }
        }

        var textColor: UIColor {
            switch self {
            // add cases if you want different colors for different styles
            default: return .white
            }
        }
    }

    var style: CustomUILabelStyle = .title {
        didSet {
            // update the label's properties after changing the style
            if style != oldValue {
                configureLabel()
            }
        }
    }

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureLabel()
    }

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        configureLabel()
    }

    func configureLabel() {
        font = style.font
        textColor = style.textColor
    }

}
```

You use it like this:

```
let label = CustomUILabel()
label.style = .title
// label.style = .subtitle
```

Comment: Any preferred suggestion on setting the style through attribute inspector in storyboard?